# Strange unhandled exception

Tags: .net, serial-port, windows

I've been developing a windows app in .net C# for GSM Modems and i've come across a strange error:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException was unhandled
  Message="The secure parameter identifier was closed (pt: O parâmetro identificador seguro foi fechado)"
  Source="System"
  ObjectName=""
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.GetOverlappedResult(SafeFileHandle hFile, NativeOverlapped* lpOverlapped, Int32& lpNumberOfBytesTransferred, Boolean bWait)
       at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.EventLoopRunner.WaitForCommEvent()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

This has only happened recently - i have no idea why... could it be i am disposing of a SerialPort and getting an answer of the modem later?? 
- shouldn't this be avoided when i dispose of the SerialPort?

Comment: It may be helpful if you could add a quick translation of what the non-english part of the error message says.  That info may be useful, and unfortunately, too many of us who speak English as a primary language can't understand any other :(

Comment: It's a translation of the english message, "The secure parameter identifier was closed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.ObjectDisposedException always occurs when you are trying to use disposed object, so you've answered on you question by your own =)

Answer (score 0):

Did you register a handler on the port's DataReceived event?  If so, you should probably unregister it (and maybe add a Sleep() call to allow any currently running handler to finish) before closing the port.